# Using powershell to manipulating xml file dom and creating another xml file

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am having an xml file shown below. By using powershell i need to copy the connectionStrings tag to another xml file.

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
   </system.web>
   <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
         <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
         <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
      </compilers>
   </system.codedom>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add connectionString="uid=u1;pwd=p1;database=d1" name="connect1" />
   </connectionStrings>
 <Appsettings>
      <add key="key1" value1="value1" />
  </Appsettings>
</configuration>
```

After copy the destination xml should look like this. And the destination xml is a new file and it is not existing.

**Output.xml**

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
      <add connectionString="uid=u1;pwd=p1;database=d1" name="connect1" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

How do i achieve this in powershell using xml dom manipulation. Any sample code of XML manipulation of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, and can be used to delete other nodes on other docs.

```
$Nodes = @("system.web","Appsettings","system.codedom")
$XMLFile = "C:\Config.xml"

$XMLDoc = (Select-Xml -Path $XMLFile -XPath /).Node
$ParentNode = $XMLDoc.configuration

$xml2 = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$newNode = $xml2.ImportNode($ParentNode, $true)
$xml2.AppendChild($newNode)

Foreach($Node in $Nodes) {
    $Delete = $xml2.SelectSingleNode("//$Node")
    $Delete.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Delete)
}

$xml2.Save("C:\Output.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Is it possible to create a destination xml from powershell instead of creating from the source xml? It is difficult to predict how many elements are there in source xml. But destination xml is alway the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I got some clue from your answer. Thank you so much for the help. Updating solution which i got. It might be helpful for others.

```
$connectionString = "connectionString.config"

[xml]$SourceConfigXml = Get-Content -Path "$connectionString" -Raw
$SourceXmlNode = $SourceConfigXml | Select-Xml -XPath "/connectionStrings"
Write-Output "$SourceXmlNode"

$xml2 = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
[System.XML.XMLElement]$configurationRoot=$xml2.CreateElement("configuration")
$xml2.appendChild($configurationRoot)

[void] $configurationRoot.AppendChild($xml2.ImportNode($SourceXmlNode.Node, $true))
$xml2.Save("C:\temp\sample\sample1.xml")
```